# How to check if string has at least 6 characters, one capital letter and one number? - Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

as the title says I would like to check if a string contain at least 6 characters, one capital letter and one number, is required to use a `regex` or there is a simplier way to achieve this?

Example of string: `Hello7`

I need help to create the regex to do this, can you give me some help? at least how to say that I required minimum a specific number of characters, thanks.

Comment: What have you done to try and solve this yourself? How familiar are you with regular expressions? Have you researched how to write regular expressions?

Comment: This is not a good use of regular expressions, especially if your required characters can appear in arbitrary positions within your test string.

Comment: Go play around a bit in a regex tester.  This is one example but there are many others and you can look for one that suits you best.  https://regex101.com/

Comment: Why downvote? forgive me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.{6}).*
```

[online demo](https://regex101.com/r/F032l5/2)

**it's just three `(?=.*pattern)` "lookaheads" in a row. Note the `.*` inside each lookahead to enable the pattern to scan the whole string. The last `.*` is just there to consume the rest of the string in case the three lookaheads succeed, and it's presence is purely optional, as in either case, "isMatch" or equivalent should be `true`.

Comment: And if you could now explain it so it's useful to others in future and not a black box to be thrown at a problem in the hope it might just work?

Answer (score 1):

You can write a single regex, but it will be convoluted. Instead you could:

```
var title = 'Hello7';
title.match(/\d/) && title.match(/[A-Z]/) && title.length >= 6 // => true
```

Comment: then my password shall be: `    H7` (4 spaces and then `H7`)

Comment: @SeanBright I can only see a requirement for character length, not amount of letters (except for at least one capital). Also it's not a password, but a title.

Comment: I know, I was just trolling. This is how I would implement as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)